# Add DLL in other Class Library to be used by actual project C#

Tags: c#, dll

I am wokring on a C# Win-Forms application. I have my own ClassLibrary (dll) file. I use another Third party dll for components. I use both of the above dll's in my C# application. When I provide the files I got to provide both the dll's seperately. Is it possible to add third party dll in my class library OR add both in a third dll and add only 1 dll in the project.

Also let me know how it is possible, as I am unaware with it. I use Visual Studio C#. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sadly to say, but no, is not possible

Comment: This isn't the kind of problem a simple Setup and Deployment project cannot solve.  Gets the .NET framework installed too, if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking up [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx); it's intended to build composite libraries.

Comment: One thing you must be careful of is the license on the other dll you are merging, doing a ILMerge of a LGPL library without making your program LGPL will violate the license, if you distribute the dll in it's own file you are fine.

Comment: You should add that as an answer, I'll give it an upvote, excellent point.

Comment: It's not really a answer, just a caution if you use ILMerge. I agree with you that ILMerge is the best solution, if licensing is compatible.

Answer (score 1):

See [Merging .NET assemblies using ILMerge](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mergingassemblies.aspx) for how to merge two assemblies

You can download ILMerge utility provided by Microsoft from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630)

Answer (score -1):

you can merge the two libraries only if you have the source codes, then you can compile the two in one single assembly. other than that it might be well possible to merge the two assemblies but its gonna be a pain in the butt depending on each library. why bother? deploy both of 'em [:

Comment: probably misunderstood me .. lemme rephrase that, its perfectly possible to merge managed assemblies, but i have come across some cases where merging two libraries can impose difficulties, depending on what each of the libraries do .. ill go with deploying each assembly separately